# How to make a Sprint Boot + Security application redirect host-relative

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an application running in a tomcat behind a apache instance. Requests from the apache are proxied via mod_rewrite since this is possible to configure in a .htaccess and I do not have access to vhost-configuration (mod_jk is not even installed).

.htaccess looks like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?my-app/(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/my-app/$1 [P]
```

Thymeleaf nicely attaches the context-name to all URLs and generates relative ones like `/my-app/relative/path` (so without the `http://hostname`-part) thru-out the HTML, which work perfectly in this setup.

Unfortunately as soon as I use Spring MVC to redirect something...

```
@RequestMapping("/redirect-to-relative-path")
public String redirect() {
    return "redirect:/relative/path";
}
```

...the users get redirected to `http://localhost:8080/my-app/relative/path` instead of just `/my-app/relative/path`, which will not work for outside users.

Also Spring Security redirects not-yet-authorized users to `http://localhost:8080/my-app/login` instead of just `/my-app/login`.

I know that I could just use a full URL to redirect to, but this should be dynamic.

What is the best (spring-boot-)way to make the framework redirect to relative URLs instead of attaching the hostname? (...basically like Thymeleaf is doing it)

Answer (score 0):

The protocol standard says that Redirect URLs should (must?) be absolute.

Try setting `proxyName` and `proxyPort` in your Tomcat configuration:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" ... proxyName="www.mycompany.com" proxyPort="80"/>
```

These should be the public properties of the Apache instance.

Comment: Thanks! Good point. Tried that proxyName/-Port locally and can confirm it works. However I'm afraid on that target box as I'm not allowed to change the apache config, I'm also not allowed to change the server.xml. Re: protocol standards [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) states: "An obsolete version of the HTTP 1.1 spec (IETF RFC 2616) required a complete absolute URI for redirection. [..] most popular web browsers tolerate the passing of a relative URL and, consequently, the updated HTTP 1.1 spec (IETF RFC 7231) [..] allowing the use of relative URLs in Location headers."